# How to export vertex color baked from Grasshopper,Rhino3d’ analyses in game engines like Unity, Unreal or directly in the webXr in real time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grasshopper, rhino3d

I am pretty new to this community.

I was wondering how to export Vertex color of Karamba, Ladybug’s analysis (color mapping) from Grasshopper/Rhino 3D in order to create an AR application (with unity, unreal or other)?

I am trying to visualize the analysis, that I baked in Rhino from other grasshopper plug-in like ladybug, karamba, honeybee, butterfly, in unity or unreal. And also, I would like to understand more deeply how the texture, materials and shaders work in Rhino and Unity within the GPU.

Comment: The normal export can be done with Export Vertex in the .obj. I presume for the real time can be done in C# writing a .txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rhino6 Support Export Vertex Color,
You can also use from Ladybug Texture Mixer from Antonello di Nunzio that can do the work, replacing the colour vertex with Texture and Material.

```
def makeTexture(size, colorTree):
    sb = size * 2 - 1
    bm = System.Drawing.Bitmap(size * 2, size * 2)
    bmb = System.Drawing.Bitmap(size * 4, size * 4)

    count = -1
    for x in xrange(size):
        for y in xrange(size):
            count += 1
            if count < len(colorTree):
                bm.SetPixel((x * 2) + 0, sb - ((y * 2) + 0), colorTree[count][0])
                bm.SetPixel((x * 2) + 1, sb - ((y * 2) + 0), colorTree[count][1])
               bm.SetPixel((x * 2) + 1, sb - ((y * 2) + 1), colorTree[count][2])
                bm.SetPixel((x * 2) + 0, sb - ((y * 2) + 1), colorTree[count][3])

    g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmb)
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
   g.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0, size * 4 + 1, size * 4 + 1)

    return bmb
```